# "Screen Time" and "Screen Active" time under Battery settings differs significantly; Gmail's Screen Active time is double the actual time

Tags: iphone, ios, battery

[image]

I'm using an iPhone 14 Pro running iOS 16.1.1, and there seems to be a discrepancy in the data shown by Apple on two of its pages (as show in the screenshots):

1. The "Screen Active" time under Battery settings 8:31h for 28 Nov (screenshot 1), whereas the "Screen Time" for the same duration is only 5:42h (screenshot 2), which is a more accurate estimate of my usage. Shouldn't they both be the same ideally? For context, the phone charged to 100 percent overnight and I didn't use it until 6:30 am, so the 8:31h SoT is for the day until 2:19 PM.
2. My Gmail "Screen Time" is 2:17h (was on a Meet call, screenshot 3), but the time is almost doubled under Battery "Screen Active" Time (screenshot 1). It shows 4:25h screen on, which wasn't the case. Similar discrepancies are there for WhatsApp and other apps. Because of this the Screen Active time is inflated, giving the false impression of a great battery life. Why is there this discrepancy? I have reset my phone and this problem still exists. Is this an app issue or iOS issue?